# Docusign http 400 Bad request

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I am trying to find envelop id status in DocuSign and getting error bad request http 400; Please verify below SOAP request.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="soap">
   <S:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>XXXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">YYYY</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </S:Header>
   <S:Body>
      <ns0:RequestStatus xmlns:ns0="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
         <ns0:EnvelopeID>a7b6af7c-3a88-42e6-b454-42ccca6c879d</ns0:EnvelopeID>
      </ns0:RequestStatus>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope
```

Thanks,
Shan

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign SOAP API has two working endpoints that your integration can use:

- https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx
- https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx

These two endpoints offer the same core platform functionality, the main difference is how they handle authentication.  The `/dsapi.asmx` endpoint requires SOAP UsernameToken auth whereas the `/api.asmx` requires the custom X-DocuSign-Authentication header auth.

Since you are using the **UsernameToken** in your request can you confirm that you are pointing to the **DSAPI** endpoint?

---

For reference, here is a sample SOAP UsernameToken header:

```
<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
  <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-0741d0e0-529f-49bc-bf86-653238d2532b">
  <wsu:Created>2006-01-02T21:26:04Z</wsu:Created>
  <wsu:Expires>2006-01-02T21:31:04Z</wsu:Expires>
  </wsu:Timestamp>
  <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-8d4e766e-a8a2-4bb3-a327-89c34bc7f85f">
    <wsse:Username>caa26663-927b-4800-bfdf-d115d1c72f20</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce>RumCR4p6U4a7hiX9lUlGWA==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2006-01-02T21:26:04Z</wsu:Created>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Comment: i tried same SOAP header for dsapi.asmx but it's gives User_Authentication_Failed - Missing authentication header. please provide  valid sample SOAP header.

Answer (score 0):

Per [SOAP DSAPI.ASMX and API.ASMX Endpoints](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Introduction+Changes/SOAP%20DSAPI.ASMX%20and%20API.ASMX%20Endpoints.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____4), The main advantage of the DSAPI.ASMX endpoint is that it performs authentication using the X-DocuSign-Authentication header instead of the WSE3 UsernameToken.

As shown in the snapshot, You need to add `header` as `X-DocuSign-Authentication` with `value` as `<DocuSignCredentials><Username>dsuseremail@email.com</Username><Password>dsuserpassword</Password><IntegratorKey>hj******-****-****-****-**********09</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>`

[image: Sample SOAPU UI Call snapshot]