# Error when generating DocuSign JWT Token in Java

Tags: java, jwt, docusignapi

I've downloaded the [JWT Auth sample code](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-java-jwt)

I've gone through and created my integrator app and added private keys.

Modified the ExampleBase.java file for additional logging.

```
OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = null;
    System.out.println("Client ID: " + DSConfig.CLIENT_ID);
    System.out.println("IUG: " + DSConfig.IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID);
    System.out.println("Scopes: " + scopes);
    System.out.println("Private Key: " + privateKey);
    System.out.println("Token Exp: " + TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS);

    try {
        oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
                DSConfig.CLIENT_ID,
                DSConfig.IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID,
                scopes,
                privateKeyBytes,
                TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error ---IO Exception---");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println("Error while update/fetching token!");
        System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.err.println(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        System.err.println("API Exception!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Code output

```
Sending an envelope. The envelope includes HTML, Word, and PDF documents. It takes about 15 seconds for DocuSign to process the envelope request... 
Token: null

Fetching an access token via JWT grant...
Client ID: cdb3.......2100207
IUG: 7......6
Scopes: [signature]
Private Key: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEogIBAADrH3w0OwPqp0iSLfDgx3kmiCxdnUW6oGUl
llBBsrkaTrPh4DGbFZhS8XiRbwuAFTWkHbLltYP0VoVHmBUhJomPie9+nAfuSWqh
kll5z/ygcGs7Vrn/mZcXTg4VihLzLphlV4FHBfwneQxq/PVIT0U=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Token Exp: 3600
API Exception!
com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting an access token: POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned a response status of 400 Bad Request
    at com.docusign.esign.client.ApiClient.requestJWTUserToken(ApiClient.java:740)
    at com.docusign.example.jwt.ExampleBase.updateToken(ExampleBase.java:62)
    at com.docusign.example.jwt.ExampleBase.checkToken(ExampleBase.java:40)
    at com.docusign.example.jwt.SendEnvelope.sendEnvelope(SendEnvelope.java:54)
    at com.docusign.example.jwt.JWTExample.main(JWTExample.java:24)
Done. Continuing...

DocuSign Exception!
    Reason: 0
    Error Reponse: null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm invoking DocuSign API Client requestJWTUserToken and call fails with 400 Bad Request. Could it be the JSON body or am I missing some else?

### Update

After reading online, I figured out that we had to convert the key into pkcs8 format (Java). [This](https://gist.github.com/destan/b708d11bd4f403506d6d5bb5fe6a82c5) really helped me in parsing the keys and generating a Java Keypair. Still running into issues with the generating token.

Comment: The sample code is pretty lousy - the "APIException" handler doesn't  give you any clue what went wrong.  SUGGESTION: Change `System.err.println("\nDocuSign Exception!");` to `e.printStackTrace();`, and update your post with the stack traceback.

Answer (score 1):

OK - thank you for modifying the code to get a stack traceback.

This is a known problem, documented here:

> https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/187
>
> Hello, The Usage example on the ReadMe works just fine against the
> Sandbox environment.
>
> However, using the same code but with my production userid, and OAuth
> base path of "account.docusign.com" returns a 400 Bad Request error.
>
> It is reproducible 100% of the time.

You're coding in Java (not C#), but it sounds like the same issue.

> I've already created a ticket, #04233413. There hasn't been any
> responses from the CS team since June 25th (2018).

SUGGESTION:

Try looking at these links:

- [DocuSign_eSign::ApiError (Bad Request)](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client/issues/9)
- [DocuSign API Integration Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54861255/)
- [Docusign http 400 Bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992240)